# Evaluate code with access to context of passed in block

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
def do_stuff(parameter)
  raise StandardError
end

def foo(parameter)
  rescuer { do_stuff(parameter) }
end

def rescuer
  begin
    yield # evaluate passed block
  rescue StandardError
    puts parameter # evaluate this with having access to `parameter` from block
  end
end

foo('bar')
#=> bar
```

What's the least hacky way of achieving this?

Comment: There is no non-hacky way of doing this, if there is any way at all. You're trying to access a variable that you have absolutely no access to.

Comment: @meagar I am sure you got my idea. I was looking for some clean way to achieve something like this without a need to alter/pass binding and so on. I haven't found it but I was pretty sure I missed something simple here. The big goal is to be able to wrap other methods into rescuer and handle exceptions there. One idea is to make `parameter` an instance variable, but I wanted something smarter. And yes, I know that I don't have access to that variable :)

Comment: As ugly and messy as it is, the passing the binding is going to be the cleanest way of doing this. As you know, local variables are meant to be local, and trying to access them goes against the "standard" and is going to be ugly. Ugly code is supposed to look ugly in Ruby. Unless this is specifically for some extreme edge case, I would personally rethink my structure of what I am doing and do it differently.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 for sure having to go "ugly" in 99% of the time means a need to rethink the approach. In this case I was just wondering if I had missed anything simple for my purpose

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Unfortunately, I don't think you missed anything that I am aware of. Using bindings is best way I would know. Might be able to hack something up using Trace, but it would only be uglier yet.

Answer (score 1):

There's a kind of messy way to do this that's highly situational, but this works in this narrow case:

```
def rescuer(&block)
  begin
    yield
  rescue StandardError
    p block.binding.local_variable_get(:parameter)
  end
end
```

The [`binding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Binding.html) on the block gives you access to any/all local variables that happen to be defined.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, knew about this one. I realized that it is not worth it (it's almost never worth it when you have to hack). I went with a clean way - passing the parameter to `rescuer`)